# Oracle data pump import job list

Tags: oracle, view, datapump

Once monthly we are doing full export of production database and import those data into develop environment. Version of Oracle database is 11.2.0.3 on RHEL 6.4 (64bit). 
My question is can i get list of those completed import/export data pump jobs, by querying data dictionary view or by using some other way?

Thank you

Comment: I don't think that is possible unless the jobs are scheduled through `dbms_scheduler`

Comment: They are not, because we do not have exact time when we do it, its random date, we wait for developers to approve this, then we execute manually a shell script on server side.